# can't ping my Access point RPI although it says connected

Tags: raspbian, networking, debian, archlinux

okay, I started configuring my access point and then I tried to connect to it.
until now both access point and client don't have ip addresses.
I give it manually an ip address 12.12.12.12/24 to my access point ( which interface I have wlan0 and after hostapd i have another one named mon.wlan0 )
and of course set the ip address of the client 12.12.12.13/24 ( he is connected via wpa_supplicant command )

Now the problem when I ping from the client it didn't pass still frozen ?
Please help !!

Comment: Can you better explain your network topology? You have a regular access point to which you're connecting the Pi? You have one Pi running hostapd and another Pi that's connecting to it? Have you checked /var/log/messages or tried running wpa_supplicant with the -d parameter and without -B to see if it's reporting any errors?

Comment: ok ubuntu <---> Raspberry pi(hostapd) <----> router

Comment: usually the install dhcp server with hostapd. but I want to give manually ip addresses

Comment: OK. You have an Ubuntu laptop or something with Wi-Fi, trying to connect to hostapd running on the Pi. I'd try running wpa_supplicant with debugging enabled as I previously suggested. It may be worth checking on the Pi as well if any errors are being reported.

Comment: wpa_supplicant connect with no problems

Comment: do i have to use dhcp server so it can work

Comment: No, you should be able to get it to work with static IPs. How are you setting them? Is there perhaps a firewall blocking ping?

Comment: no I don't have firwall i'l just trying to connect two laptops as though they are connected with ethernet link

Comment: I really appreciate your help Mr.Fred !